# object Object вместо строки ввода React

Tags: reactjs

Пишу небольшую тудушку на реакте, сама не очень хорошо в этой теме разбираюсь. У меня есть такая вот форма в которую нужно вписывать задачи, но почему то когда я начинаю писать оно выбивает [object Object] и я не могу вписать что то другое.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import {
    List, ListItem,
    TextField
} from 'mdc-react';

import './index.scss';

export default function TodoForm({ onSubmit }) {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState('');

    function handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        onSubmit(title);
        setTitle('');
    }

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="todo-form">
            <List>
                <ListItem>
                    <TextField
                        label="Добавь задачу..."
                        value={title}
                        onChange={setTitle}
                        fullWidth
                    />
                </ListItem>
            </List>
        </form>
    );
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А где ваш setTitle?

Answer (score 0):

Вы inputu сделали `value={title}` и `onChange={setTitle}`, это значит что при каждом вводе значение title будет изменяться на то что вы ввели и если хотите писать что-то свое, то просто записывайте результат в переменную и не выводите value
Тоесть `value={title}` уберите

Answer (score 0):

Так должно работать.

```
onChange={(event) => setTitle(event.target.value)}
```

Посмотри про Контролируемые компоненты.
https://ru.react.js.org/docs/forms.html

Comment: спасибо большое, сработало.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста